# Windows PowerShell stay cursor after run the command

Tags: powershell

When I use the **PowerShell.exe** on Windows, Sometime I see the last **cursor shape** after executed last command:
[image]

Comment: Please show output of `$PSVersionTable` and include the Windows version/build number :)

Comment: Nice. And what is your question?

Comment: Might be a bug; if it is one, it's likely not one in PowerShell but the (new) terminal instead. There are [108 open issues](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+cursor) mentioning the cursor and I can't see one that looks immediately relevant, but who knows, it might be in there.